# How to unit test an UrlHelper custom helper method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, nunit

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3` and `NUnit`.  I am trying to write a unit to test one of my helper methods.  Here it is:

```
public static class UrlHelperAssetExtensions
{
   private static readonly string yuiBuildPath = "http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/";

   public static string YuiResetFontsGridsStylesheet(this UrlHelper helper)
   {
      return helper.Content(yuiBuildPath + "reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css");
   }
}
```

Here is my unit test:

```
[Test]
public void YuiResetFontsGridsStylesheet_should_return_stylesheet()
{
   // Arrange
   RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext();
   UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);

   // Act
   string actual = urlHelper.YuiResetFontsGridsStylesheet();

   // Assert
   string expected = yuiBuildPath + "reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css";
   Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Am I testing it the correct way?  When I run it in the NUnit GUI then I get the following error:

System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: httpContext

Is this possible to test?  If so please explain in clear how do I get an instance of httpContext?

**UPDATED**

I can't get this test to pass.  In my method I have the following:

```
private static readonly string stylesheetPath = "~/Assets/Stylesheets/";

public static string Stylesheet(this UrlHelper helper)
{
   return helper.Content(stylesheetPath + "MyStylesheet.css");
}
```

The test that I wrote for it is the following:

```
private string stylesheetPath = "/Assets/Stylesheets/";
private HttpContextBase httpContextBaseStub;
private RequestContext requestContext;
private UrlHelper urlHelper;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
   httpContextBaseStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();
   requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContextBaseStub, new RouteData());
   urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
}

[Test]
public void Stylesheet_should_return_stylesheet()
{
   // Act
   string actual = urlHelper.Stylesheet();

   // Assert
   string expected = stylesheetPath + "MyStylesheet.css";
   Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

The NUnit GUI gives the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It seems to be getting the error with the ~ in:

```
private static readonly string stylesheetPath = "~/Assets/Stylesheets/";
```

Comment: Call stack for your exception could help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to mock HttpContext. Here's the example using [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/):

```
// Arrange
   var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
   RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(context.Object, new RouteData());
   UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);
```

If you do not want to use a mocking framework, you can create a class that will derive from HttpContextBase and use it instead. But this will require implementing a lot of abstract members, which you can avoid by mocking it.

Comment: Thanks. How do you know which one of the 2 RequestContext parameters to mock?  Why just the one and not both?

Comment: @Brendan - You do not need to mock RouteData, you can just create an instance. You would probably populate it with your route definitions first.

Comment: do you agree with Darin's answer above?  Your answer passes the test, so it is necessary to do it Darin way?

Comment: @Brendan - No, but if you want to add a dependency to MvcContrib (and there are nice things there) than you might want to use TestHelper. Depending on what you are testing there may be a need to mock more properties in HttpContext. It's really up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like using [MVCContrib TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper):

```
// arrange
// TODO: You could move this part in the SetUp part of your unit test
// to avoid repeating it in all tests
var cb = new TestControllerBuilder();
cb
    .HttpContext
    .Response
    .Stub(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(Arg<string>.Is.Anything))
    .WhenCalled(mi =>
    {
        mi.ReturnValue = mi.Arguments[0];
    })
    .Return(null);
var rc = new RequestContext(cb.HttpContext, new RouteData());
var helper = new UrlHelper(rc);

// act
var actual = helper.Stylesheet();

// assert
Assert.AreEqual("/Assets/Stylesheets/MyStylesheet.css", actual);
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me what it is you are doing after var cb = new TestControllerBuilder();?

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, I am stubbing the `Response.ApplyAppPathModifier` method which is internally used by the `UrlHelper.Content` method. I use the `WhenCalled` construction which allows me to provide a return value which is based on the call parameter. So in this case I simply return the value used as argument. It wouldn't be possible to achieve this with a simple `.Return` because we don't know with what argument this method will be called. I agree that the syntax is a little complex but that's how Rhino Mocks does it. In `Moq` IIRC you could specify directly a return value based on input.

Comment: @Brendan Vogt, what Jakub did is only part of what's needed. If you don't mock the Response and the ApplyAppPathModifier method you will simply get a NullReferenceException.

Comment: I tried just Jakub's code and it didn't throw any exception.  Can you please just verify that this is correct?